# Google Tag Manager + Universal Analytics does not fire for outbound links

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement google analytics with outbound clicks tracking using Google Tag Manager. I have the following tags set:

> Google Analytics Universal - Page View - Firing rules: All pages
>
> All Clicks - Link Click Listener - Firing rules: All pages
>
> External Links Tracker - Universal Analytics - Event - Firing rules:
>   External link

The external link rule is defined as follows:

> {{event}} equals gtm.linkClick
>
> {{element url }} does not start with http://example.com
>
> {{element url }} does not start with http://www.example.com

When I run the GTM in debug it seems to be working but when I publish it, it does not work. Analytics only collects the normal traffic but no events for outbound clicks.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would emphasize that the issue is when I push the code. In debug mode, it works ok. I can debug the events being fired. But not when live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**checklist**,

I think the answer is quite simple - you have to create two rules, because if you include both conditions (with WWW and without WWW), you have to consider the operator being used. GTM in using using AND operator by default, so this tag would fire if both of the conditions would be matched AT the same time. Which will never happen :)

**To avoid a situation when you URL is in {{element url}} (as a parameter), creating a simple rule with regular expression should do the trick:**

*Rule 1) Outbound WWW*

```
{{event}} equals gtm.linkClick
{{element url }} does not match RegEx ^http:\/\/([a-z]*\.)?example\.com
```

Comment: thanks but this does not work. The rule is now fired for ANY click on a link. I think this is because each rule by itself is true for local links

Comment: what if you switch to does not contain?

Comment: I cannot use does not contact because my links can have a referrer in them as a parameter (e.g. http://example2.com?page?referrer=http://example.com

Comment: also, regular expression might do the trick and you could actually simplify it to just one rule: ^((?!example\.com).)*$

Comment: let me update the regex to take care of the parameters

Comment: can you try this one: ^((?!example\.com/).)*$

Comment: I used ^http:\/\/([a-z]*\.)?example\.com and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: good, I have updated the answer. would you mind accepting it?

Comment: just did. maybe since i had a part, you can like my Q ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{element url}}` does not contain example.com

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot, since some of my urls have example.com in them as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
{{element url}} does not match regex  ^http://(www\.)?example\.com
```